# Извлечь домены из из текста

Tags: php

1.На входе есть строка(Строка для примера, она может быть очень большая):

> 49    0   0 wiki.nashtransport.ru wiki.nashtransport.ru/  27184   23232
>   mignews.ru    mignews.ru/27182    67  сергиев-посад.рф тут еще какая-то инфа.
>   domen.ru тут куча текста

2. Нужно выбрать со строки все доменные имена.

Т.е. На выходе должно получиться следующее:

```
wiki.nashtransport.ru
mignews.ru
сергиев-посад.рф
domen.ru
```

Как реализовать подобное?

Comment: Собирай регулярным выражением весь текст от пробела до слеша

Comment: подскажи, текст регулярного выражения. Я просто не знаю регулярки.

Comment: Я сам не сил`н в регулярках. Возможно этот пример:


    $text="49 0 0 wiki.nashtransport.ru wiki.nashtransport.ru/ 27184 2323";

    
    if (preg_match_all("!\s(.*?)/!si",$text))

Comment: почти то, что нужно. Исключение - не срабатывает маска касательно начала строки.

Comment: нужно регулярку настроить чтоб она выбирала текст не с пробела до слеша а в обратную сторону

Comment: Попробуйте перевернуть строку затем перевернуть результат ----$text="49 0 0 wiki.nashtransport.ru wiki.nashtransport.ru/ 27184 2323";---- 
---strrev($text);---
---$result=if (preg_match_all("!\(.*?)\s!si",$text));---
strrev($result);--

Comment: ошибка в последнем комменте, вот так попробуйте ---$result=if (preg_match_all("!СЛЭШ(.*?)\s!si",$text));--- (заменив слово СЛЕШ на обратный \ )--  с перевертыванием

Comment: по-всякому пробую, не выходит пока что.

Comment: Я думаю если вы с помощью strrev($text); перевернете текст то вам всего лишь нужно взять текст между символами( \ весь текст \s ) где \s-это пробел

Comment: Напиши плиз синтакс вот этого момента - "( \ весь текст \s )", не разберусь никак. Сделал так - "(.*?)\s" - не работает.

Comment: $result=if (preg_match_all("!..(.*?)\s!si",$text));  -- (после .. поставь \ )--тут обратный слеш в комментах блочится чтоли. в регулярке что я его пишу он в итоге пропадает. проверил вот так работает, но только если изначальная строка перевернута

Comment: В общем в ответ пример вставил, там обратный слеш не исчезает

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $text="49 0 0 wiki.nashtransport.ru wiki.nashtransport.ru/ 27184 2323 49 0 0 wiki.nashtransport.ru1 wiki.nashtransport.ru1/ 27184 2323 49 0 0 wiki.nashtransport.ru2 wiki.nashtransport.ru2/ 27184 2323";

    // переворачиваем текст для извлечения строки между \ и пробелом
    $text=strrev($text);

    preg_match_all("!/(.*?)\s!si",$text,$result);





foreach($result as $key=>$val) 
  {
        foreach($val as $key=>$vals) 
        {
            if (preg_match("/^([a-z\d](-*[a-z\d])*)(\.([a-z\d](-*[a-z\d])*))*$/i",$vals))
            { 


            // переворачиваем текст обратно
            $vals=strrev($vals);

            echo $vals."</br>";


            }
        }

   }

?>
```

Comment: Сами тестровали работоспособность кода?

Comment: Исправил на полностью готовый код. И проверил.

Answer (score 1):

Изначально имеем текст:

```
$text = '49 0 0 wiki.nashtransport.ru wiki.nashtransport.ru/ 27184 23232 mignews.ru 
mignews.ru/27182 67 сергиев-посад.рф тут еще какая-то инфа. domen.ru тут куча текста';
```

Воспользуемся следующим регулярным выражением:

```
preg_match_all('~[\w.-]+(?:ru|рф)~mui', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

В результате получаем:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => wiki.nashtransport.ru
            [1] => wiki.nashtransport.ru
            [2] => mignews.ru
            [3] => mignews.ru
            [4] => сергиев-посад.рф
            [5] => domen.ru
        )
)
```

Если регулярное выражение захватит неправильные доменные имена, то вы можете отфильтровать массив доменов, следующим способом:

```
$array = array_filter($matches[0], function ($x) {
   return (filter_var('http://'.($x), FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) ? true : false;
});

print_r($array);
```

Но, в [мануале](http://php.net/manual/ru/filter.filters.validate.php) написано:

> Обратите внимание, что эта функция считает корректными только URL, состоящие из символов ASCII; Интернациональные доменные имена не пройдут проверку.

Поэтому следует сначала воспользоваться библиотекой **IDNA**, к примеру [эта](https://github.com/phlylabs/idna-convert).

Например, домен `сергиев-посад.рф` в итоге преобразуется в `xn----8sbedibbx1djfkj.xn--p1ai`. Тем самым в итоге он пройдет проверку с фильтрацией URL.